# how do I point my compiler and linker in Eclipse and Windows?

Tags: compiler-construction, boost, windows-7, linker, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded boost. The instructions at the website said this:

> In this example, you would point your linker at C:\lib\boost\lib and tell your compiler to search for includes in C:\lib\boost and include them using the second boost directory, for example #include "boost/filesystem.hpp

How exactly do I point my linker and compiler?

I'm working in Eclipse on Windows 7.

Comment: I've not used CDT in a while, but under the C/C++ tab in project properties under the G++ linker page there is an option to add libraries. You add the boost lib directory under environment variables if am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

**Compiler**: To add include directory, add boost path in:

```
project properties->C\C++ Build->Settings->Directories->GCC C++ Compiler->Directories
```

Note: add the folder in which the folder *"boost"* resides, so you can do

```
#include "boost/smart_ptr.hpp"
```

**Linker**: To add libraries path, add a *search path* (pointing to where all lib files are) in:

```
project properties->C\C++ Build->Settings->Directories->MinGW C++ Linker->Libraries
```

(This assumes you're using the MinGW toolchain. Should be the same on other toolchains).

Cheers